# Сайт с использованием Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Подскажите, как сделать сайт, используя Google App Engine.
Есть ли видеоуроки/сайты, где это подробно написано. Только не посылайте в гугл.
Много пишется везде, но не пишется как.

Answer (score 2):

Google App Engine не самый подходящий выбор для размещения сайта. Он больше специализируется на размещении веб-приложений написанных на Java и Python.
На Java можно написать сайт используя Google Web Toolkit и легко размещать его на Google App Engine используя встроенный Плагин в Eclipse.
Вряд ли где то будут описаны уроки создания сайтов - он не совсем для этого.
Ссылки по теме.
http://habrahabr.ru/post/140123/ 
http://habrahabr.ru/post/141398/

Answer (score 1):

[Вот](http://www.martynj.com/host-website-free-appengine) урок, по которому я разобрался и сделал пару сайтов-затычек ([например](http://www.mute8.com/)), и бесплатно держу их в Google App Engine. Статичные одностраничники плюс отправка мне на почту из формы.

Без гугла тут не обойтись, всё же : ) Стоит посмотреть на примеры из их [документации](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/).

P.S. небольшой отстой состоит в том, что нельзя направить на GAE-сайт "голый" домен без www. Приходится делать редирект.